# Библиотека для распознавания звуков?

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Хочу с помощью питона распознать звук, например, хлопок в ладоши.

Как или с помощью какой библиотеки можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю тебе нужно `speechpy`.
Для установки нужно в консоли ввести:

```
pip install speechpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
from q1461770_SWHear import SWHear


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(993, 692)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pbLevel = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.pbLevel.setMaximum(1000)
        self.pbLevel.setProperty("value", 123)
        self.pbLevel.setTextVisible(False)
        self.pbLevel.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.pbLevel.setObjectName("pbLevel")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pbLevel)
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.grFFT = PlotWidget(self.frame)
        self.grFFT.setObjectName("grFFT")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.grFFT)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.grPCM = PlotWidget(self.frame)
        self.grPCM.setObjectName("grPCM")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.grPCM)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.label.setText("frequency data (FFT):")
        self.label_2.setText("raw data (PCM):")
        

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        pyqtgraph.setConfigOption('background', 'w') 
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.grFFT.plotItem.showGrid(True, True, 0.7)
        self.grPCM.plotItem.showGrid(True, True, 0.7)
        self.maxFFT = 0
        self.maxPCM = 0
        
        self.ear = SWHear(rate=44100, updatesPerSecond=20)
        self.ear.stream_start()

    def update(self):
        if not self.ear.data is None and not self.ear.fft is None:
            pcmMax = np.max(np.abs(self.ear.data))
            if pcmMax > self.maxPCM:
                self.maxPCM = pcmMax
                self.grPCM.plotItem.setRange(yRange = [-pcmMax,pcmMax])
            if np.max(self.ear.fft) > self.maxFFT:
                self.maxFFT = np.max(np.abs(self.ear.fft))
                self.grFFT.plotItem.setRange(yRange=[0,1])
            self.pbLevel.setValue(1000 * pcmMax / self.maxPCM)
            pen = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color='b')
            self.grPCM.plot(self.ear.datax, self.ear.data, pen=pen, clear=True)
            pen = pyqtgraph.mkPen(color='r')
            self.grFFT.plot(self.ear.fftx, self.ear.fft / self.maxFFT,
                            pen=pen, clear=True)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, self.update) 

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    form.update()                            
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1461770_SWHear.py**:

```
import pyaudio
import time
import numpy as np
import threading

def getFFT(data,rate):
    """ Given some data and rate, returns FFTfreq and FFT (half). """
    data = data * np.hamming(len(data))
    fft = np.fft.fft(data)
    fft = np.abs(fft)
    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft), 1.0/rate)
    return freq[:int(len(freq)/2)], fft[:int(len(fft)/2)]

class SWHear():
    """
    The SWHear class is provides access to continuously recorded
    (and mathematically processed) microphone data.
    
    Arguments:
        
        device - the number of the sound card input to use. Leave blank
        to automatically detect one.
        
        rate - sample rate to use. Defaults to something supported.
        
        updatesPerSecond - how fast to record new data. Note that smaller
        numbers allow more data to be accessed and therefore high
        frequencies to be analyzed if using a FFT later
    """

    def __init__(self, device=None, rate=None, updatesPerSecond=10):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.chunk = 4096                       # gets replaced automatically
        self.updatesPerSecond = updatesPerSecond
        self.chunksRead = 0
        self.device = device
        self.rate = rate

    ### SYSTEM TESTS

    def valid_low_rate(self,device):
        """ set the rate to the lowest supported audio rate. """
        for testrate in [44100]:
            if self.valid_test(device, testrate):
                return testrate
        print("SOMETHING'S WRONG! I can't figure out how to use DEV", device)
        return None

    def valid_test(self,device,rate=44100):
        """ given a device ID and a rate, return TRUE/False if it's valid. """
        try:
            self.info = self.p.get_device_info_by_index(device)
            if not self.info["maxInputChannels"] > 0:
                return False
            stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1,
                input_device_index=device, frames_per_buffer=self.chunk,
                rate=int(self.info["defaultSampleRate"]), input=True)
            stream.close()
            return True
        except:
            return False

    def valid_input_devices(self):
        """
        See which devices can be opened for microphone input.
        call this when no PyAudio object is loaded.
        """
        mics = []
        for device in range(self.p.get_device_count()):
            if self.valid_test(device):
                mics.append(device)
        if len(mics) == 0:
            print("no microphone devices found!")
        else:
            print("found %d microphone devices: %s" % (len(mics), mics))
        return mics

    ### SETUP AND SHUTDOWN

    def initiate(self):
        """ run this after changing settings (like rate) before recording """
        if self.device is None:
            self.device = self.valid_input_devices()[0]     # pick the first one
        if self.rate is None:
            self.rate = self.valid_low_rate(self.device)
        self.chunk = int(self.rate / self.updatesPerSecond) # hold one tenth of a second in memory
        if not self.valid_test(self.device, self.rate):
            print("guessing a valid microphone device/rate...")
            self.device = self.valid_input_devices()[0]     # pick the first one
            self.rate = self.valid_low_rate(self.device)
        self.datax = np.arange(self.chunk) / float(self.rate)
        msg = 'recording from "%s" ' % self.info["name"]
        msg += '(device %d) ' % self.device
        msg += 'at %d Hz' % self.rate
        print(msg)

    def close(self):
        """ gently detach from things. """
        print(" -- sending stream termination command...")
        self.keepRecording = False                  # the threads should self-close
        while(self.t.isAlive()):                    # wait for all threads to close
            time.sleep(.1)
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.p.terminate()

    ### STREAM HANDLING

    def stream_readchunk(self):
        """ reads some audio and re-launches itself """
        try:
            self.data = np.fromstring(self.stream.read(self.chunk), dtype=np.int16)
            self.fftx, self.fft = getFFT(self.data, self.rate)
        except Exception as E:
            print(" -- exception! terminating...")
            print(E, "\n" * 5)
            self.keepRecording = False
        if self.keepRecording:
            self.stream_thread_new()
        else:
            self.stream.close()
            self.p.terminate()
            print(" -- stream STOPPED")
        self.chunksRead += 1

    def stream_thread_new(self):
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.stream_readchunk)
        self.t.start()

    def stream_start(self):
        """ adds data to self.data until termination signal """
        self.initiate()
        print(" -- starting stream")
        self.keepRecording = True   # set this to False later to terminate stream
        self.data = None            # will fill up with threaded recording data
        self.fft = None
        self.dataFiltered = None    # same
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1,
                      rate=self.rate, input=True, frames_per_buffer=self.chunk)
        self.stream_thread_new()

if __name__=="__main__":
    ear = SWHear(updatesPerSecond=10)          # optinoally set sample rate here
    ear.stream_start()                         # goes forever
    lastRead = ear.chunksRead
    while True:
        while lastRead == ear.chunksRead:
            time.sleep(.01)
        print(ear.chunksRead, len(ear.data))
        lastRead = ear.chunksRead
    print("DONE")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хлопок преобразованиями фурье ловить не совсем корректно. Мне кажется есть более простой алгоритм, ведь детектор хлопка реализуют в бареметал.